# Animation glitch when remove from list after fetching data in firestore

Tags: list, animation, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm a beginner in SwiftUI and I am developing an app that require fetching data in Firestore to show them in a list.
The user is able to remove an item from the list. When he does that I remove the ID from the item witch is in an Array in my User document in firestore.

It works pretty well but there is no animation when the removal is effective and it's pretty hard to the eye... How can I change my code so the user sees a smooth animation when he removes the item ?

Here is my code :

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth

struct SendToPatientsView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @StateObject private var viewModel = AppViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            List{
                ForEach(viewModel.userPatients) { patient in
                    NavigationLink{
                        PatientView(results: .constant(patient.patientUID))
                    } label: {
                        Text(patient.patientFamilyName + " " + patient.patientGivenName)
                    }
                    .swipeActions {
                        Button{
                            Task{
                                    do {
                                        try await removeFromPatients(patientUID: patient.patientUID)
                                        
                                    } catch {
                                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                                    }
  
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .task {
                await viewModel.fetchUserData()
                try! await viewModel.getMyPatients()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func removeFromPatients(patientUID: String) async throws{
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        try await Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userID).updateData(["patients": FieldValue.arrayRemove([patientUID])])
        await viewModel.fetchUserData()
        try await viewModel.getMyPatients()
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

**Code Update**
I forgot to show my fetchUserData() and getMyPatients(). Here is the code :

```
func getAddedPatients() async throws -> [Patient]{
        let viewModel = AppViewModel()
        await viewModel.fetchUserData()

        var userPatient: [Patient] = []
        
        if let myProfile = viewModel.myProfile {
            for id in myProfile.patients {
                guard let patient = try? await Firestore.firestore().collection("Patients").document(id).getDocument(as: Patient.self) else {return []}
                userPatient.append(patient)
            }
        }
        
        return userPatient
    }


func fetchUserData() async{
        guard let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{return}
        guard let user = try? await Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userUID).getDocument(as: User.self) else {return}
        await MainActor.run(body: {
            myProfile = user
        })
    }
```

Solution found :
Using .onDelete instead of .swipeAction and delete the item locally and then in firestore works pretty well.

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        let indices = Array(offsets)
        for index in indices {
            let patient = viewModel.userPatients[index]
            Task {
                do {
                    try await removeFromPatients(patientUID: patient.patientUID)
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You aren't showing enough code to represent the issue, but if you want an animation, one strategy is to wrap the code that manipulates the collection in a `withAnimation { .. }` block

Comment: @jnpdx I added my functions that fetch user data and patients in my first post. But I cant use with animation with asyncronous function...
Thanks by the way :)

Comment: Still not enough code to reproduce the issue. It's not clear where `getAddedPatients()` lives or why it's creating a separate `AppViewModel`. Using `withAnimation { }` can be done inside an async function. Like I said, where you manipulate the collection, wrap the manipulation in `withAnimation { }`

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks again for responding my stupid question 
I found a solution that works using .onDelete instead of .swipeAction and delete the item locally then in firestore.

Comment: In that case, you should post an answer, or remove the question

Comment: Yep I just did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .onDelete instead of .swipeAction and delete the item locally and then in firestore works pretty well.

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        let indices = Array(offsets)
        for index in indices {
            let patient = viewModel.userPatients[index]
            Task {
                do {
                    try await removeFromPatients(patientUID: patient.patientUID)
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```